# More efficient way of writing native links for multiple websites

Tags: html, hyperlink

nooblet here with a quick question since I couldn't find anything on this already asked. Is there a more efficient way of writing native links. Using css and anchor points in links perhaps.

Example: 
Instead of using this
`<a href="/code/images/example.png">`
On one site then on another use: 
`<a href="../random/code/images/example.png">`
Just because they are in different folders.

Is there a way to have a file anchor point like: `<a href="{anchorpoint}/code/images/example.png">`

Thank you :).

Comment: Consider `<base />` HTML tag.

Comment: `/code/images/example.png` will always be the same from any relative URL…!?

Comment: @deceze If the file has a different parent folder it will be different?

Comment: What does "parent folder" mean exactly? URLs starting with `/` are relative to the domain; i.e. when you're visiting the URL `http://example.com`, on any page on that domain the URL `/foo/bar` will ***always*** refer to `http://example.com/foo/bar`.